# Writing a Query in php that gets information from 2 different tables

Tags: php, postgresql

I am writing my last query for my homework, but I am stuck on it right now. This query requires me to take information from 2 tables instead of 1. I am confused on how to get this information from both tables and how to put them together. Here is the description of the query that I am trying to write.

```
For each country display the capital city name and the percentage of the population that lives in   
the capital for each country. Sort the results from largest percentage to smallest percentage.
```

For this query I believe I am going to have to get the population of the whole country, then get the population of the capital city and then divide them in order to get the percantage of the population that lives in the capital. I just cant wrap my head around how I am going to perform this math especially when the data comes from 2 different tables. Thanks for the help in advance. Here are the tables that I am going to use for this query

```
Table "lab2.city"
Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                     
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
 population   | integer               | not null default 0
Indexes:
"city_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"city_country_code_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES country(counry_code) ON DELETE CASCADE


 => \d country
                           Table "lab2.country"
 Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              

-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
continent       | continent             | not null
region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
indep_year      | smallint              | 
population      | integer               | not null default 0
life_expectancy | real                  | 
gnp             | real                  | 
gnp_old         | real                  | 
local_name      | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
government_form | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
head_of_state   | character varying(60) | default NULL::character varying
capital         | integer               |
```

Comment: INNER JOIN is your friend.

Comment: Not going to give you the whole answer, but you want to use the inner join like the previous comment states.  
Your assessment is correct that you'll need to take the population from the city and divide it by the country population, then you'll multiply by 100.
When you join two tables, you can set an alias, which is the key to the math equation:
SELECT * FROM lab2.city c 
JOIN lab2.country c2 ON c.country_code = c2.country_code
Now, if you say c2.population it will be the country population.  If you use c.population it will use the city population value.

Comment: @espradley does this look correct?

    SELECT name FROM lab2.city c JOIN lab2.country c2 ON c.country_code = c2.country_code


I dont get it I need to keep trying haha

Comment: You already asked this. What's the difference? Show what you have already tried and where you got stuck if you want to post a follow-up. This website isn't "do my homework for me" ... be specific, show what you've already done. In this case I would expect to see a query using a correct `inner join` per your last question and a question about how to then use the resulting join-table. Also, per my recommendation in the last question, did you **follow the tutorial**?

Comment: @user3596818 (Replying to comment on deleted answer): Looks like the same to me, just you expanded this one a bit. This is even a copy and paste of the first part of the previous one. The answer remains the same: use an inner join. Follow the tutorial. If you're still stuck after going through the tutorial you can post a more specific question with the query you've tried and the error you're getting / the point at which you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry I just dont understand how your explaining it

Comment: @user3596818 Did. You. Read. This. Web. Page.: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html ?? If not, *go do that*. Somebody else has already handed you the answer to the first part of your question on the earlier post you made. So start with that. Run it interactively in `psql` or `PgAdmin-III`. Play around and learn.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question because it's closed as a duplicate of your other question. Actually, just don't vandalize your question.

Comment: A fellow student actually *tried to solve the problem* before they asked for help here. Here's how to do it right: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25924304/398670

Answer (score 1):

You can select all needed columns while using a join statement.

Comment: ... and then do what with them? It sounds like the poster needs to do some simple aggregation or other maths on them.

Comment: You're right.

It seems like you have to sum the population by country to get the percentage of population in a capital. This could be done with the help of a sub query.

The easiest way is to start with only one country while trying to find the solution.

I would start to sum the population for a country. Next you should be able to get the percentage of population of a capital in that country. Now you should add all needed columns and lastly change the query so that it works with all countries.

Comment: I dont think its that complicated

Comment: I'm sure this is a really easy way.

Comment: @Radhad It is. It's just an `INNER JOIN`, a `WHERE` clause, an `ORDER BY` and a percentage calculation in the `SELECT` list. Tutorial 101 stuff, which you probably realise. I've (repeatedly) linked to resources that'll let the asker learn how to do this and answer their own question, as is appropriate for homework, but they seem to want a pre-written answer handed on a plate.

Comment: @CraigRinger sure, if you don't learn it by yourself, you'll never understand how to find a solution next time. That's also why I don't post a possible SQL query here.

Comment: @Radhad Yup. Reminds me of my university tutorial days. Them: "I'm stuck, how do I do <X>". Me: "Well, see this syntax error saying that there's no such function? Where did you define the function? Does the name look the same?". Them: "But ... how do I do <X>, can you show me?". Me: *headdesk*